# LESS grid not compiling correctly in CQ5.6.1

Tags: css, compilation, less, aem

The code below I have created to make a loop for a grid i'm setting up for my website.
On my CQ5.6.1 website it doesn't compile, but when I compile the code on less2css.org it works perfectly.

Adding this specific part in CQ5.6.1 the LESS compiler breaks the entire clientlibs. I know it's this specific part because if I just remove these lines everything works again.

So is there a limitation on the variables in CQ5.6.1 or something or does anyone have see what the issue is with this specific code

```
@containerwidth: 960;
@iterations: 12;
@margin-grid: 10;
@startwidth: 940; /* containerwidth - (margin-left + margin-right) */
@startprefix: @containerwidth;
@startsuffix: @containerwidth;
@startpush: @containerwidth;
@startpull: -@containerwidth;

.grid-loop (@index, @width, @prefix, @suffix, @push, @pull) when (@index > 0) {
.grid-@{index} {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: unit(@margin-grid, px);
    margin-right: unit(@margin-grid, px);
}

.push-@{index}, .pull-@{index} {
    position: relative;
}

.container-12 {
    .grid-@{index} {
        width: unit(@width, px);
    }

    .prefix-@{index} {
        padding-left: unit(@prefix, px);
    }

    .suffix-@{index} {
        padding-right: unit(@suffix, px);
    }

    .push-@{index} {
        left: unit(@push, px);
    }

    .pull-@{index} {
        left: unit(@pull, px);
    }
}
.grid-loop(@index - 1, @width - 80, @prefix - 80, @suffix - 80, @push - 80, @pull + 80);
}

.grid-loop (@iterations, @startwidth, @startprefix, @startsuffix, @startpush, @startpull);
```

Comment: I added this code to one of the LESS files I use in CQ 5.6.1 in a large client library and it compiled without error for me.

Comment: indeed seems you code to compile well in the newest version 2 of Less, but also in older releases, so your problem do seems to be related to Less